# type 'CategoriesScreen' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Tags: flutter

dart showing the error type 'CategoriesScreen' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast. whereas CategoryScreen is another page which has assigned to tab bar screen .whereas I tried making dynamic instead of Object but it didn't works .please give me explanation about that

[image]

```
import 'package:dishes_app/Screens/Categories_screen.dart';
import 'package:dishes_app/Screens/Favourites_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TabsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabsScreenState createState() => _TabsScreenState();
}

class _TabsScreenState extends State<TabsScreen> {
  final List<Map<String, Object>> _pages = [
    {'page': CategoriesScreen(), 'title': 'Categories'},
    {'page': FavouriteScreen(), 'title': 'Your Favourite'}
  ];
  int selectedpageindex = 0;
  void _selectPage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      selectedpageindex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_pages[selectedpageindex]['page'] as String),
      ),
      body: _pages[selectedpageindex]['page'] as Widget,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: _selectPage,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber,
        currentIndex: selectedpageindex,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              icon: Icon(Icons.category),
              title: Text('Categories')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            icon: Icon(Icons.star),
            title: Text('the Favourite'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this type cast error because you are trying to cast  `widget` in to `String` in below code.

```dart
 appBar: AppBar(
   title: Text(_pages[selectedpageindex]['page'] as String),
  ),
```

Comment: thanks ,  it works with string interpolation

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `AppBar` you are trying to put a class to a String.

Use:

```
appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_pages[selectedpageindex]['title'] as String),
      ),
```

Instead of:

```
appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_pages[selectedpageindex]['page'] as String),
      ),
```